# Java: Gregorian Calendar date validation issue

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I’m trying to validate a date input by a user using the Gregorian Calendar in java (this is a must), however whenever I test a date in December it throws up the error below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH   
        at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(Unknown Source)  
        at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Unknown Source)  
        at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Unknown Source)  
        at java.util.Calendar.getTime(Unknown Source)
```

code below

```
public static boolean  ValidDate (int Day, int Month, int Year)  
    GregorianCalendar Date = new GregorianCalendar();  
    Date.setLenient(false);  
    Date.set(Year, Month, Day, 0, 0, 0);  
    try{  
        Date.getTime();  
        return true;  
        }catch (Exception e){  
            System.out.println("Date is invalid please try again");   
            return false;  
        }  
}
```

I haven’t been able to turn up anything relevant on google so any help would be awesome!

Comment: By the way, your example code fails to abide by Java conventions for formatting. A method name should start with a lowercase letter. Variables including arguments should also start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( year , month , dayOfMonth )  // Catch exception `DateTimeParseException`
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes rather than the troublesome old `GregorianCalendar` class.

The [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

To validate your inputs, attempt to assemble a `LocalDate` from the numbers. Unlike `GregorianCalendar`, `LocalDate` has sane numbering of months, 1-12 for January-December. If the numbers result in an invalid date, a [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) is thrown for you to catch.

```
try {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( year , month , dayOfMonth ) ;
    return true ;  // true = Valid data entered for a date.
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    return false;  // Exception caught, meaning invalid data-entry.
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 10):

With the Calendar class, although days and years *are* numbered `1..n` (one-based), months are numbered `0-11` (zero-based), so December is **not** month number `12`, it is month number `11`.

Try calling your method specifying `11` (instead of `12`) for the month parameter.

This issue is just *one* of the many challenging aspects of the Calendar class.

Answer (score 3):

Or, better yet, use the constant `Calendar.DECEMBER`.  You don't have to worry about whether it's 11 or 12 under the covers.

Do yourself a favor: learn and follow the Java coding standards.  I'd write it this way:

```
public static boolean  isvalidDate (int day, int month, int year)  
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setLenient(false);  
    calendar.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);  
    try {  
        date.getTime();  
        return true;  
     } catch (Exception e) {  
        return false;  
     }  
 }
```